# Module and subtraction of two random variables of uniform distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, graphing-functions

Having X~Uniform(0,1), Y~Uniform(0,1) independent what's the pdf of r = |X - Y|. If I want plot f(r=|X - Y|) against X, what should I do?

about the plot, at first I thought of doing, $r^2 = (x - y)^2$, and call $y=\rho$, but it did not work.

Comment: Hint: $|X-Y|\leqslant t$ if and only if $X-Y\leqslant t$ and $Y-X\leqslant t$.

Comment: I recommend you look at the highest-voted solution in the post that I linked. I believe it answers everything you ask about.

Comment: @Math1000 thank you.